# Hidden button shown on mouse over other div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a header with 5 image buttons

```
<div id="header">
<a href="#" onClick="goto('#Omeni', this); return false"><div id="centeredOmeni"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="goto('#folio', this); return false"><div id="centeredFolio"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="goto('#folio2', this); return false"><div id="centeredFolio2"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="goto('#stor', this); return false"><div id="centeredStor"></div></a>
<a href="#" onClick="goto('#kont', this); return false"><div id="centeredKont"></div></a>
</div>
```

Where I would like button with id centeredFolio2 to be shown on centeredFolio:hover and available for click. All 5 buttons have a different background-image on hover in CSS and I would like to keep that. I am fine with a solution either CSS or jQuery, I could find a working solution which works on divs inside a href like these. The button either stayed undisplayed or it never got hidden.

Here is jsFiddle without the effect http://jsfiddle.net/nqmf7/

Thank you.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is missing the goto function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery hover dependent on two elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132006/jquery-hover-dependent-on-two-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that might work for you, using jQuery's `mouseover()` method:

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nKvTC/)</kbd>

First of all, you must add `display:none;` to the css for div `#centeredFolio2`:

```
display:none;
```

Next, you can use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#centeredFolio').mouseover(function() {
        $('#centeredFolio2').show();
    });
    $('[id^=centered]').not('#centeredFolio, #centeredFolio2').mouseover(function() {
        $('#centeredFolio2').hide();
    });
    $('#centeredFolio2').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        alert('You clicked the button');
    });

}); //END document.ready
```